# Jenkins Confluence Publisher - wiki markup plain text to add data in a new row

Tags: jenkins, macros, confluence, wiki-markup, confluence-macros

How can we append/add new row/new cell at the top of the table, to act as the first row, below the headers using wiki mark up tokens. ?

I use Jenkins confluence publisher to send values from Jenkins build to a cell in a table in the confluence page. As I run the job daily, I need the Jenkins job to append the new details at the first row and eventually the yesterday's job details will be pushed down to the second row.

`before21` token returns results that should come under the `column H1` while `before 31` values under `column H2`. I tried to create a cell within the existing cell using `|cell|` and `{{!}}`, but none of them works for me as these tokens are inside the table. As shown in the screenshot below, the values are getting added to the same cell instead of new cell.

I am unsure if I can create a row for  `before21` and use the same new row for `before31`. The values for these tokens are passed as plain text option from the  Jenkins confluence publisher, which will eventually be in the new rows. The plain text supports wiki markup format.
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/confluence-publisher/

Can you guys please direct me where am I doing wrong and how can I achieve this?

I use confluence 7X. In Edit mode the page looks like
[image: The expected data to publish]

This is post update

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achieved by posting content in HTML format.

Comment: can you share an example? @Y5288? how did it really shift the rows