# Jenkins Confluence Publisher - add data to a new cell

Tags: jenkins, confluence, confluence-macros

I have an empty table on confluence. I wish to append rows to it with build data from Jenkins,i.e., every time a build passes/fails, I want to add a new row with the results. How do I do that from Jenkins using the [Confluence Publisher plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/confluence-publisher/)

As of now, I was able to update just a page using the command -

```
publishConfluence editorList: [confluenceAppendPage(confluenceText("${some value}"))], pageName: 'a page that I want to update', parentId: 1234, siteName: 'foo.com', spaceName: 'DCM'
```

I tried using markers, but I'm sure how to make them invisible on the confluence page nor how to automatically add a new marker on the page so that the next job updates the row.

Any help here is appreciated. This talks about using HTML content but not sure how [Jenkins Confluence Publisher - wiki markup plain text to add data in a new row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61927432/jenkins-confluence-publisher-wiki-markup-plain-text-to-add-data-in-a-new-row)